# WP7 Visual State Problems

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, coding-style

**UPDATE:**

Download a small test app [here](http://cid-478bda4dd05d096a.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/CustomControlProblem2.zip)

I have a custom control consisting of a border, button and textblock. When the control is pressed I display a popup picker control. I'm having a problem using visual state to properly enable and disable the control.

When I enable and disable the control normally using the Normal and Disabled visual state it works fine:

Enabled:

[image: Enabled]

Disabled:

[image: Disabled]

If I click the control then disable the control the background stays white:

[image: disabled]

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: I think that I am missing a property in my visual state that is getting set by the system. I'm hoping someone can identify what it is so I can override it.**

Here is the style:

```
<Style
    TargetType="Controls:PickerBoxButton">

    <Setter
        Property="Background"
        Value="Transparent" />

    <Setter
        Property="BorderBrush"
        Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

    <Setter
        Property="Foreground"
        Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

    <Setter
        Property="BorderThickness"
        Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}" />

    <Setter
        Property="FontFamily"
        Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />

    <Setter
        Property="FontSize"
        Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />

    <Setter
        Property="Padding"
        Value="8,3,8,5" />

    <Setter
        Property="Template">

        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate
                TargetType="Controls:PickerBoxButton">

                <Grid
                    Background="Transparent">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <VisualStateGroup
                            x:Name="CommonStates">

                            <VisualState
                                x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PickerButton"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PickerText"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                </Storyboard>

                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState
                                x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PickerButton"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PickerText"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border
                        x:Name="ButtonBackground"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Margin="6,8,8,0"
                        >

                        <Button
                            x:Name="PickerButton"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Height="64"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Margin="-12,-12,0,-12"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Width="700">

                            <StackPanel
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Width="700">
                                <TextBlock
                                    x:Name="PickerText"
                                    Margin="-2, 0, 0, 0"
                                    />
                            </StackPanel>

                        </Button>

                    </Border>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

UPDATE

Added code from control showing visual state change trigger.

```
private bool _isReadOnly;
public bool IsReadOnly
{
    get { return _isReadOnly; }
    set
    {
        _isReadOnly = value;

        UpdateVisualState();
    }
}

private void UpdateVisualState()
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, IsReadOnly ? "Disabled" : "Normal", false);
}
```

Comment: Hi what do you mean by 'click the control then disable the control'? Can you show me the code that disables the control? Thanks.

Comment: Meant touch the control so it has focus then set the IsReadOnly property of the control to true which calls the VisualStateManager.GotoState passing Disabled. See code above and Visual state in Style. Changing to a Disabled state works when the control does not have focus but the text ends up white when the control has focus. Must be a property I'm not setting in the visual state but cannot find which one.

Comment: could it because when the control gets focus, the underline button is in pressed state, the button itself doesn't know it should be disabled as you didn't set it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>From your description, you are setting IsReadOnly to true but this won't make the control go to the Disabled state. You should set IsEnabled to False instead. Can you please give it a try?</strike>

Wonder if this would work... In your PickerBoxButton's constructor, do

```
    this.IsEnabledChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState((PickerBoxButton)s, "Disabled", true);
    };
```

and in wherever you set your IsReadOnly property, replace it with

```
 this.YourCustomControl.IsEnabled = false;
```

---

With your sample project, I found when animating a rectangle instead of button and textblock it actually worked as expected. Then I suspected this might because GoToState triggers the underlying controls' visual states to change as they share the same visual states names. I then changed your visual states names from 'Normal' to 'NormalState', 'Disabled' to 'Disabled', then everything worked. :)

Also please remove the code I gave to you, and use your original IsReadOnly property to trigger the state change.

Comment: Have tried this. Couldn't set IsEnabled directly on control as this is one of a number of controls that implements an interface and IsReadOnly is an interface menber so in IsReadOnly setter I set IsEnabled then checked for IsEnabled in visual state change. Good news is background changes to dark when disabled. Bad news is background stays dark when enabled again. Pretty sure there is a background property that needs to be set in the visual state that is being set by the IsEnabled change instead. I need to find that property.

Comment: sorry i am not 100% sure why you can't set the IsEnabled property in your custom control. is it inherited from Control? would you mind showing me the full code of your custom control? thanks

Comment: I could set IsEnabled if I wanted to but I would rather set it indirectly. Same result either way. Main problem now is background is not getting set back when IsEnabled set to true. Am going to make a test solution showing the problem. Will post location soon.

Comment: Have created a small test app and uploaded here http://cid-478bda4dd05d096a.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/CustomControlProblem.zip Normal state has red background. Disabled state has yellow background. When click disable button background turns dark grey. When click enable button background turns yellow. No idea why yellow as that should e the disabled colour.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested and uploaded a new zip file http://cid-478bda4dd05d096a.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/CustomControlProblem2.zip Pressing Disable then Enable correctly disables then enables the control. Now Press the control (button) then press Disable - the background stays red. This is the original problem I posted. Not sure why changing to Disabled State when button not clicked OK but changing to to DisabledState when button clicked has problems.

Comment: terribly sorry... i wasn't testing it properly... i have uploaded a file to http://cid-f9ac8aa3f6afdcc3.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/CustomControlProblem3.zip what i did was i removed the background color from your button and created a Rectangle as the background color. this time it should work. for some reason, the click of the button breaks its background animation and i am not sure why... another question i wanna ask if why not create a Button control instead of a custom control? in that case you already got the default visual states defined for you and you won't have the same issue...

Comment: also i tested this behavior in a silverlight 4 project n doesn't seem to be able to produce the same issue.

Comment: Works great. Thanks for all the time and effort you put into this Xin.